# RequireJS optomization without Node.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, requirejs, amd

I have RequireJS running on my IIS server, for my MVC web app.

Is it possible to make RequireJS pick up the minified versions of the files, rather than their unminified? Visual Studio makes all of these files and they seem to be going to waste.

My understanding of NodeJS servers is they can open the javascript files to send dependencies aswell, but I cannot see that happening with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build in way to tell requirejs to use the minified versions. You could replace the files in your source directory with the minified versions, r.js has an option for this. Or redefine the source path of your js files, dependent on the environment the application is running.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer, but I hope someone else can post a hack or work around.